# Check if a string starts with the a specific word, if True then print word - PYTHON

Tags: python, string, list, compare, match

I have a list of strings, I want iterate through each and check if the string begins with the word "Base", if it does, I would like to print it.

the list

```
SideMembers = ["Unweighted Base","Base: All GB Adults","A savings account","None of these"]
```

Here are my attempts

```
for word in SideMember:
    if word[0] == "B":
        print word
```

This works but its not very robust as you can see, I dont exactly know how to compare the the whole word.

```
for word in SideMember:
    if "Base" in word:
        print word:
```

This doesnt really work as it prints `SideMembers[0]` and `SideMembers[1]` since both of those contain "Base".

Would appreciate some help...

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`str.startswith()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith):

```
for word in SideMember:
    if word.startswith('Base'):
        print word
```

It does exactly as you would expect it to do ;).

By the way, you [should only use capitalised variable names for classes](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

---

Some other methods you probably shouldn't consider, but for the fun of it I included them :p

```
import re
for word in sidemembers:
    if re.search(r'^Base', word) is not None:
        print word

for word in sidemembers:
    if word[:4] == 'Base':
        print word
```

Comment: I must not've searched hard enough as I didnt come across that! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks for the additional codes. I was trying to figure out a way to do "word[:4] == "Base", why should i not consider this? i thought his would've been the answer?

Comment: @Boosted_d16 You could, yea, but I prefer using `startswith()` because it's more readable